# docker 18.06 docker-compose does not find entrypoint.sh

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Since I updated docker to 18.06, the "docker-compose up" command does not find my entrypoint.sh script anymore. Before the update everything worked well.

**The error I get:**

> ERROR: for phoenix  Cannot start service phoenix: OCI runtime create
>   failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused
>   "exec: \"/app/entrypoint.sh\": stat /app/entrypoint.sh: no such file
>   or directory": unknown
>
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

**I also set the execution rights for entrypoint.sh in the Dockerfile:**

```
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

OS: windows 10 pro,
docker: 18.06.0-ce,
docker-compose: 1.22.0

Please let me know if you had the same issue and how you solved it.

Comment: remove / from the beginning of the path

Comment: @bxN5 this does not work. Like I said, before the update to 18.06 this code worked fine

Comment: try `ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]`

Comment: @Pitt this also does not work

Comment: The most common cause I’ve seen for this issue in this setup is adding a shell script with DOS line endings into a Linux container; it tries to run /bin/sh\r and doesn’t find it.

Comment: @DavidMaze the "file entrypoint.sh" command gives me "entrypoint.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable", so I think the line endings is also not the problem

Comment: Does your image actually have bash in it?  Some very-light-weight images don’t.  If you’re not using any of the bash extensions (and you can get quite far without them) marking your script `#!/bin/sh` to work with any POSIX shell might work.

Comment: Can you post your docker-compose and dockerfile?

Comment: i suspect your volume directory share is not working. so it could not find the file. first you may need to fix the directory share.